# How to validate a column in an editable datatable?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Am using an editable HTML datatable on my asp.net web page .Which look like this,
[image]

How to add validation on column Target, to receive only float values.?

**Function** (For enable edit):

```
function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
  var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
  var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
  jqTds[0].innerHTML = aData[0];
  jqTds[1].innerHTML = aData[1];
  jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="Float" class="form-control" value="' + aData[2] + '">';

  jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<a class="save-row" href="">Save</a>';
  jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel-row" href="">Cancel</a>';

    }
```

I tried to add keypress event on the textbox , but its not working.!

```
$('#Float').keypress(function (event) {
           if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && (event.which != 8)) {
               event.preventDefault();
           }
       });
```

Am new to jquery so please help me solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try:

  onload =function(){ 
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll('.number-only')[0];
  ele.onkeypress = function(e) {
     if(isNaN(this.value+""+String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)))
        return false;
  }
  ele.onpaste = function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
  }
}

Note: Above code doesn't work for -ve values.
```